# Opening project shows layers on layer panel but no map

Tags: qgis

I created a project using QGIS 3.0.3 on Ubuntu 18.04. I can open the project and the layers show up in the Layers panel. However, I don't see any map. I can see the data if I go into Attribute Table but I can't go from there to seeing the map again.

Comment: Do you mean that the map canvas is blank, or that there's no map canvas at all in the QGIS window?

Comment: The map canvas is blank. For example, I can open a shapefile but if I open the project, I don't see the map associated with the project, even if I see all layers (and the relevant are "checked") in the Layer panel.

Comment: Did you try right-clicking on a layer and choosing the option "Zoom to Layer"?

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I tried after not seeing a map

Comment: If you start a new project, set the project CRS to EPSG:3857, add a QuickmapServices background, then one of your layers, does it show up at the right place on the Earth?

Comment: I started a new project and couldn't get the "old" layer to show up anywhere. Because it was a time-sensitive thing, I decided to start from scratch. I don't think I did anything differently but the layers in the new project do show up when I reopen it. The old one doesn't. Thanks for the suggestions.